# Parse input fields as a Array list to controller via @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, thymeleaf, request-mapping

I want to submit all textfields and radiobuttons from my input fields as an ArrayList and parse it to the controller but I don't know really how.

Any help is really appreciated.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formdata", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String formdata(HttpServletRequest req, @AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser, 
                       @ModelAttribute RegDatas regDatas, Model model) {
    // get values as regDatas[0]?
}
```

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/formdata}" th:object="${regDatas}">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input th:field="*{regDatas[0].gender}" type="radio" value="MALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled" /><span>Mr</span>
    <input th:field="*{regDatas[0].gender}" type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled"/><span>Frau</span>
    <p>Firstname:</p>
    <input required="required" type="text"  th:field="*{regDatas[0].firstname}" placeholder="Max" disabled="disabled" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input th:field="*{regDatas[1].gender}" type="radio" value="MALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled" /><span>Mr</span>
    <input th:field="*{regDatas[1].gender}" type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="gender" disabled="disabled"/><span>Frau</span>
    <p>Firstname:</p>
    <input required="required" type="text"  th:field="*{regDatas[1].firstname}" placeholder="Max" disabled="disabled" />
    <button type="submit">Speichern</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My wrapper class:

```
public class RegDatas {

    private List<RegData> regDatas;

    public List<RegData> getRegDatas() {
        return regDatas;
    }

    public void setRegDatas(List<RegData> regDatas) {
        this.regDatas = regDatas;
    }

}
```

My class to store values:

```
public class RegData {

    private String email;
    private String firstname;
    private Gender gender;

    public String getEmail() {return email;}

    public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}

    public String getFirstname() {return firstname;}

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {this.firstname = firstname;}

    public Gender getGender() {return gender;}

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {this.gender = gender;}
}
```

This is the error I see if I run it like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'RegDatas[0]' of bean class [de.ciss.aag.model.domain.RegData]: Bean property 'RegDatas[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method
```

Comment: On face value this looks like it should work. What problem are you seeing? What does the `regDatas` variable contain in your controller when you do the POST?

Comment: Im getting this error org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'RegDatas[0]' of bean class [de.ciss.aag.model.domain.RegData]: Bean property 'RegDatas[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Comment: When do you see the error? Is it when you submit the form, or when you initially load the page? Do you have anything that's populating your model class? Is there anything in your `RegDatas.regDatas` list when the page loads?

Comment: The error prompts when initially loading the page. Theres nothing populating the class :/

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I think the problem is that your model is not populated with a RegDatas object. This [Baeldung tutorial - Getting Started with Forms in Spring MVC](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial), particularly section 4 is probably a good resource, if you haven't already seen it, but I think you need something like this (from the tutorial) in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
    return new ModelAndView("employeeHome", "employee", new Employee());
}
```

But you'll need to add a populated `RegDatas` instance to your model, instead of the employee, so as a very basic example, this seems to work for me, with your code. There are other ways of populating the model, that I'd recommend researching, but this is probably the most straightforward.

```
@RequestMapping("/your-page-endpoint")
public ModelAndView get() {
    return new ModelAndView("your-view-name", "regDatas", new RegDatas());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! i think i got it.. would you know maybe how to access the stored data from the controller?